# Vis.js Timeline change dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, vis.js

I would like to change timeline option dynamically.
When the document is ready I can initialize 1 or more TimeLine and foreach TimeLine I want to have possibility to change options, data or group.
I don't want to initialize global vars (will be simple to call them) because I can have 1, 2 or n timeline...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
          var items = new vis.DataSet([
            {id: 1, group: 1, content: 'item 1', start: '2013-04-17', end: '2013-04-18'},
            {id: 2, group: 2, content: 'item 2', start: '2013-04-14', end: '2013-04-15'},
            {id: 3, group: 3, content: 'item 3', start: '2013-04-16', end: '2013-04-17'},
            {id: 4, group: 3, content: 'item 4', start: '2013-04-15', end: '2013-04-16'},
            {id: 5, group: 1, content: 'item 5', start: '2013-04-18', end: '2013-04-19'},
            {id: 6, group: 1, content: 'item 6', start: '2013-04-19', end: '2013-04-20'}
          ]);
          
          var groups = new vis.DataSet([
            {id: 1, content: 'aaa'},
            {id: 2, content: 'bbb'},
            {id: 3, content: 'ccc'},
          ]);
          var options = {
            min: new Date(2013, 03, 01),
            max: new Date(2013, 03, 30),
            start: new Date(2013, 04, 01),
            end: new Date(2013, 04, 30),
            zoomMin: 1000*60,
            zoomMax: 1000*60*60*24*30, 
            stack: false,
            margin: {
              item: 20, // minimal margin between items
              axis: 10   // minimal margin between items and the axis
            },
          };
          var container = document.getElementById('mytimeline1');
          new vis.Timeline(container, items, groups, options);
          
          var items2 = new vis.DataSet([
            {id: 4, group: 3, content: 'item 7', start: '2013-04-15', end: '2013-04-16'},
            {id: 5, group: 1, content: 'item 8', start: '2013-04-18', end: '2013-04-19'},
            {id: 6, group: 1, content: 'item 9', start: '2013-04-19', end: '2013-04-20'}
          ]);
          
          var groups2 = new vis.DataSet([
            {id: 1, content: 'ddd'},
            {id: 2, content: 'eee'},
            {id: 3, content: 'fff'},
          ]);

          var container2 = document.getElementById('mytimeline2');
          new vis.Timeline(container2, items2, groups2, options);
});


  // I don't want to initialize global vars (it's simple) because I can have 1, 2 or n timeline...
  
$(document).on("click", ".setTL1", function(){
  alert("I want to change mytimeline1 settings by .setOptions()");
  // I would like to have a sintax like: 
  // var container = document.getElementById('mytimeline1');
  // container.xxxx.setOptions({
  //  ...
  // });
  // is it possible?
});
$(document).on("click", ".setTL2", function(){
  alert("I want to change mytimeline2 settings by .setOptions()");
  // I would like to have a sintax like: 
  // var container = document.getElementById('mytimeline2');
  // container.xxxx.setOptions({
  //  ...
  // });
  // is it possible?
});
```

```css
    #mytimeline1, #mytimeline2 {
      border:1px solid gray;
      padding : 5px;
    }
    .vis.timeline .labelset .vlabel .inner {
      min-height: 100px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Fixed group height</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.21.0/vis.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.21.0/vis.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body>
  <button class="setTL1">Zoom1 (ClickMe)</button>
  <div id="mytimeline1"></div>
  <div style="height:10px;"></div>
  <button class="setTL2">Zoom2 (ClickMe)</button>
  <div id="mytimeline2"></div>

</body>
```

Have you suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR: no way to go without a global variable (or some js framework), but you can define a global map (associative array, js object) to avoid having a new global var for each required timeline.

If you are not using any js framework (ext.js, Angular, and maaany more) you will have to handle/control which javascripts objects/variables you want to maintain. There is no standard DOM -> javascript object mapping.

Think in a barebones approach I would suggest having a global map of initialized timelines, and the map key could be the div id. And to make things easier to maintain, I would also suggest having a standard function to create/initilize the timelines (and eventually to change them as well). Some untested code mockup below:

```
var globalTimelines = {}; // yes, this is global.. :(
function createTimeline(containerId, rawItems,rawGroups, options) {
      var items = new vis.DataSet(rawItems);
      var groupss = new vis.DataSet(rawGroups);
      var container = document.getElementById(containerId);
      var newTimeline = new vis.Timeline(container, items, groups, options);
      globalTimelines[containerId] = newTimeline;
} 

$(document).ready(function(){
      createTimeline("mytimeline1", ....);
      createTimeline("mytimeline2", ....);
});
$(document).on("click", ".setTL1", function(){
  alert("I want to change mytimeline1 settings by .setOptions()");
  var timeline = globalTimelines['mytimeline1'];
  timeline.setOptions({
        ...
  });
});
```

Comment: I use also jQuery and I thought I have a sintax like $("mytimelineX").vis.Timeline().setOptions({...}); but maybe vis.js not allow to do it ... or this is the wrong sintax. Your solution is a good alternative. I have post a request in their "Git issue", but at the moment I haven't had reply. Thanks to you